# OpenCV SURF: Cost function between two features?

Tags: c++, opencv

OpenCV has many matchers inbuilt such as KNN and BruteForce. I would like to know if there exists some function somewhere that I can calculate the "cost" between two features and do the matching myself. Basically, I have two cv::Keypoint objects and I have the 128 vector for each. Ideally, if there is some function that can take them in and provide a single score output, or possibly some other heuristics that would be great.

Comment: For SURF, both KNN and BruteFoce simply use Euclidean distance (L2 distance) as the distance function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIFT and SURF descriptors both are just histogram. So you can use any of histogram distance metrics to find out the similarity/dissimilarity score between each pair of descriptors.

Euclidean distance and Hellinger distance are of most famous measures for this aim. But when using a distance measure, you should be sure that the function has metric features. If you are not familiar with metric features, Wikipedia described it very well: [Metric Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Definition).

OpenCV has implemented some of the most popular metric functions including [Bhattacharyya distance](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html).

Comment: Okay, but what kind of scale do i use for comparison? If I use L2 Norm, what kind of distance am i getting? How do i know if its good/minimal?

Comment: Most of the time we use RANSAC to accept or reject points. It is done through these steps: (1)taking 3 matches(3 pairs), (2)finding the Transformation between  them, (3)Counting the number of matches which are OK with the T matrix with a maximum of tolerance, (4) repeat it until there is not any better T in regard to the result of (3). => T is what you want!

Comment: a simple example without RANSAC: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html